# Parsing out key value from string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I have a file im trying to parse that is written in this format:

```
command -l KEY "VALUE"
```

My goal is to get the KEY and the VALUE, which is inside double quotes.

Every line begins with the same `command -l`.  Right now, im doing this a rather inefficient way.  I'm getting a substring deleting the first 11 characters, trimming out everything after the space and then getting another substring with the quoted characters.

Surely there must be a better way to do this and I think REGEX is that solution.  I've been following this page here but am totally lost:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Side note: Good reading on "I think REGEX is that solution" - https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple string parsing exercise like this, it's very unlikely that regex will perform significantly better than manually taking a substring then calling `string.Split(" ")`. For example:

```
public KeyValuePair<string, string> Parse(string input) {
    var split = input.Substring(11).Split(' ');
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(split[0], split[1].Replace("\"",""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a command line parser package available from nuget (like https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/1.9.71)

There are plenty of them around and then you don't have to worry about handling all error or special cases.